# Not able to fetch custom token after mint from Infura

Tags: web3j, infura

I am using web3j library with an Infura Websocket connection. I set up a subscribe method where I listen to transfer events of my custom ERC20 Token. When a transfer event occurs on the blockchain I get the information in the subscribe body and send it to my eventListener. In my eventListener I try to fetch the details of the Token from the Blockchain (over the same Infura websocket connection)

**Publisher.java**

```java
web3j.logsNotifications(List.of(customToken.getContractAddress()), List.of(EventEncoder.encode(CustomToken.TRANSFER_EVENT)))
                        .subscribe(logNotification -> {
                            Log transferEventLog = logNotification.getParams().getResult();
                            publisher.publishEvent(transferEventLog);
                        }, throwable -> {
                            logger.error("Error in subscription", throwable);
                        }, () -> {
                            logger.info("Complete transfer event subscription");
                        });
```

**Listener.java**

```java
public void transferEventListener(Log transferEvent) {
        // code to parse log -> to get id of token
        Tuple2<String, BigInteger> response= customToken._tokens(id).send();

        // Further code to handle response
}
```

The call in my listener always fails with Exception: `Request with id # timed out`
and then my Websocket connection gets closed.

If I make the same request to tokens which are minted in the past, everything works as expected!

Is it generally possible to fetch a custom token from Infura directly after they are mined? What I am doing wrong here?